# how to decode the html data from database and set value of textarea in codeigniniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am submitting text data into the database through an editor that inserts data with HTML tags into the database. Now the problem is when I retrieve data from the database and try to set the value of that text area it comes with HTML tags. How can I set value without HTML tags?

I tried this piece of code

```
set_value('detail', html_entity_decode($aboutus->imgdetail))]);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: You can remove HTML tags before save it in Database. Or you can use HTML Text Editor to Show/Edit Data in your HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set your variable you use the strip tags function like this:

```
 set_value('detail', strip_tags($aboutus->imgdetail))]);
```

Comment: `strip_tags()` does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

Comment: Yes its Done Thank You Dear @pr1nc3

Comment: Dear @pr1nc3 There is one small problem by using this strip_tags() When i got edit the content and update then it save data in database without html tags. So that the texting paragraph on frontend not appear.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to decode the HTML tags and display it in the text areas.

```
 set_value('detail', htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($aboutus->imgdetail)));
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php